# SQL: how to get unique count from unique entries?

Tags: sql, count

Simple SQL question, I searched but can't seem to find the answer already asked.

I want to query the names, and then the count of unique url per each name.

Input:

```
NAME       URL
John       google.com
John       google.com
John       youtube.com
Bob        youtube.com
Bob        twitter.com
```

Desired output:

```
NAME       URL_count
John       2
Bob        2
```

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name), COUNT(URL) as URL_count
FROM database_table
WHERE date='2013-06-12'
```

Doesn't seem to yield the results I need!  Help?

Answer (score 5):

Since you want the count of distinct `urls` for each user, the correct syntax will be the following which uses `count(distinct url)` and groups the data by the `name`:

```
select name, count(distinct url) as URL_count
from yourtable
where date='2013-06-12'
group by name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0730/1)

Comment: This doesn't work because it gives me John, John, John, Bob, Bob.  When in fact I just want unique name, and the count of unique URLs associated with each name.

Comment: @user1899415 Are you running this exact query? Using your data it is working in this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0730/1. The combination of the aggregate and the `group by` should not allow for the data to be across multiple rows.

Comment: @user1899415 You are either confused, running another query or have bad data; but this answer is correct.

Comment: Bad data can mean white space characters. [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14a16/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use the group by combined with distinct:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT URL) as URL_count
FROM database_table
WHERE date='2013-06-12'
GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT URL) as URL_count
FROM database_table
WHERE date='2013-06-12'
GROUP BY name
```